# Force android libgdx into immersive mode

Tags: java, android, libgdx, android-xml

Following the tutorials on this page(written in 2009) don't work any more. http://www.androidsnippets.com/how-to-make-an-activity-fullscreen

```
public class FullScreen extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Similarily, trying to change the theme in android.xml has no effect:`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

After scouring the web for a few hours, i cant find any articles that can help me.
So how, in version 1.5.4 of libgdx, can i get an [immersive full screen](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)?

**----EDIT----**
Here is the now fully working code:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        hideSystemUi();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        config.hideStatusBar=true;
        config.useImmersiveMode=true;
        initialize(new game(), config);
    }


    private void hideSystemUi() {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in the android activity:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

Note this will only work on API level 19 or above.

Comment: there is no Activity class.  That is why the first one did not work

Comment: Yeah there is: https://github.com/anubiann00b/TileArena/blob/master/android/src/game/tile/arena/android/AndroidLauncher.java

Your launcher extends `Application` which extends `Activity`.

Comment: huh... I don't really know then, sorry :P

Comment: Thank you so  much.  The View object has a few other flags.  This worked:  getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
         View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);

Comment: also, i noticed it didn't work unless it was followed by: config.hideStatusBar=true;config.useImmersiveMode=true;

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help! You should answer your own question with what you got, that'll be more useful for future visitors to this site.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I can't comment due to my current reputation,
however I have found that adding:

```
config.hideStatusBar = true;
config.useImmersiveMode = true;
```

in the AndroidLauncher class is enough to show the app in immersive however the app will start in standard mode and then update to immersive mode, more info on the Android immersive mode:

> When you use the SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY flag, an inward swipe in the system bars areas causes the bars to temporarily appear in a semi-transparent state, but no flags are cleared, and your system UI visibility change listeners are not triggered. The bars automatically hide again after a short delay, or if the user interacts with the middle of the screen.

[Android sdk page](http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

So my conclusion would be that config.useImmersiveMode use the sticky flag.

On a side note, 
     @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
has to be added to the OnWindowFocusChanged method when targeting an api lvl less than 11